# Laravel: get Many-to-Many column data

Tags: laravel, many-to-many, eloquent

Yo all,

I have a users relationship pivot db table as follows:

```
id | user_id | relation_id | relationship
1    4         2             tutor
1    4         3             parent
```

The table relates user with one-and-other for various reasons.

I am trying to get the relationship column within the $user. I have managed to pull the related users 
details no problem - `$user->relations`.

However, I just need to get the relationship - eg. Tutor or parent.
I am getting no dice with `$relative->pivot->relationship`

Any ideas? Thanks for taking the time to help.

```
@foreach($user->relations as $index=>$relative)
    {{ $relative->first_name . ' ' . $relative->last_name}}
    {{ $relative->pivot->relationship }}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access `->pivot->whatever` you need to add `withPivot('whatever')` to the relation definition:

```
public function relations()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('Relation')->withPivot('relationship');
}
```

---

**Note:** I wouldn't use `relations` and `Relation` names here, since it's misleading AND it may collide with `Eloquent\Model` stuff.

Comment: JACKPOT. Thanks very much Jarek. Yeah, I take your point on the relation terminology. Is there a convention you know of for users_users type tables? The later seems wrong to me. Thanks again.

Comment: Depends on the situation. It might be called `friends` for example. It's hard to suggest if I don't know your schema and application.